# A new explanation of the Newton's beads effect?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, spring

Couldn't help my self by watching Steve's Mould newest [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTLR7FwXUU4) about this [effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_fountain) to wonder if the dominant cause for this extra kick on the beads chain is the elasticity of the chain thus can be explained by Hooke's law and the stiffness constant *k* of the chain.

The whole beads chain acts exactly like a spring at the section of maximum bend giving the extra kick needed for the falling chain to rise well above, depending the *k* constant, the top of the jar.

This spring effect of the beads chain can be observed bellow:

[image: beads chain spring effect when bend]

[source video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTLR7FwXUU4&t=843s).

The higher the drop of the chain and the length of the chain dropped, the larger the velocity with time (acceleration) of the chain shooting upwards from the jar gets. Therefore, a stronger bend on the critical section of the chain generating a stronger spring effect *Fs=kx* with time.

What do you think?

Comment: This is a complicated phenomenon that may have to be successfully modeled on a computer before it is understood.